# Which one is the "correct" answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

So I asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184955/third-sub-class-slot) about the third sub-class slot in Destiny a while ago (when Destiny was still <del>cool</del> new). At the time, it was uncertain what it was for/if it was going to be used/if it was an oversight.

However now, they have announced a third sub-class for each of the new classes (which I took the liberty of adding).

So, the question is *which one is correct?* Or more specifically, *which one should I accept as the answer?* Or is that purely up to me?

Answer (score 3):

The game has changed, the answer has changed. The new answer you have provided is now the correct answer and would be marked as such.

What makes this one tricky is that if you had only just started playing with the 3rd DLC, this question is fairly obvious now.. There are three sub classes one for each slot.

But anywho.. The information in the original answer explains how the game Used to work and that simply is not the case any more. It is an interesting read for sure but you should, as noted above, mark the answer that currently answers the question correctly as the answer.

Comment: That's what confused me too. The game has changed, so the question has become irrelevant(?) obsolete(?) redundant(?).

Comment: @Ben It is up to you but if you feel the question is no longer needed you can delete your own questions. Or simply make a note in your answer of how the game was previously in the other answers and just let it be.